# How to run a script on Check out to a new branch-local

Tags: git, github

I want to run a script on checkout to a new branch in my git (local machine).
Basically when I checkout to a new branch I want to create a python package with same name as of Branch.
Is this possible?

Comment: Consider creating a bash alias that does both things so that you can simply run `my-co the-branch`.

Comment: [`post-checkout` hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_checkout)